# How to archive artifacts of parametrized build in Jenkins-ci

Tags: windows, cmd, jenkins, wdk

I have a [Jenkins](http://www.jenkins-ci.org/) build project, that builds a Windows driver module for 3-axis configuration (xp, w2k8, w2k3, w7, vista) vs (x86, x64) vs (free, checked).

How can I archive the artifacts *including* the `pdb` files intelligently. If I include the files in the jenkins setting I get an error that nothing matching `*.pdb` was found on free builds.

Better yet, how can I create `cmd` script that finds all `*.sys` and `*.pdb` files in (vbery deep) subdirectories and copies them to a certain directory?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As long as you have at least one other artifact you can write a script to copy it and all other artifacts to a predefined place in your working copy (say, a directory keyed by `BUILD_ID`, e.g. `foo_${BUILD_ID}_bar`; you create it dynamically in the script, of course). Then as a post-build step in Jenkins designate *everything* (`${BUILD_ID}/**/*`) in that directory as artifacts. It will give you a warning on the configuration page (since the directory does not exist, yet), but will run fine.

Since every sub-build in the matrix has its own workspace the artifacts won't be mixed. One issue you need to consider is how to clean-up your workspace.

Comment: This is what I ended up doing. Thanks.

Comment: Didn't work for me, it's not recognizing the variable and tries to access a path with the literal name, giving me the error: `ERROR: No artifacts found that match the file pattern "%BUILD_PATH%\*/**.apk".`
The variable `%BUILD_PATH%` is recognized correctly in all other build steps except in the "Archive the artifacts" post build step

Comment: @LuísCunha have you found a solution yet?